# struct field changed but it isn't expected

Tags: c

I'm trying to translate a sentence into morse code. I have a morse.txt file with this type of content :

```
'-','-','-','-','-',0, /* Caractère 0 */
'.','-','-','-','-',0, /* Caractère 1 */
'.','.','-','-','-',0, /* Caractère 2 */
```

In order to translate each letter from the sentence I thought about create a 2 dimension array in which we would find a letter and its translation in morse. Here's my struct

```c
typedef struct
{
    char lettre;
    char *morse;
} t_morse;
```

I created a function returning that array :

```c
t_morse *loadTab()
{
    t_morse *tabMorse = malloc(LETTER_NUMBER * sizeof(t_morse));

    ssize_t read;
    size_t len = 0;
    char index = 0, k = 0, j;
    char *line = NULL;
    FILE *f = fopen("morse.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Impossible d'ouvrir morse.txt\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (read = getline(&line, &len, f) != -1 && line != NULL)
    {
        char *morse = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
        char *stringfinal = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));

        strcpy(stringfinal, line);
        k = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(stringfinal); j++)
            if (stringfinal[j] == '-' || stringfinal[j] == '.')
                morse[k++] = stringfinal[j];
        tabMorse[index].morse = morse;
        tabMorse[index].lettre = index + 48;
        printf("lettre : %c, morse : %s\n", tabMorse[index].lettre, tabMorse[index].morse);
        index++;
        free(morse);
        free(stringfinal);
    }
    fclose(f);

    for (index = 0; index < LETTER_NUMBER; index++)
    {
        printf("toto %c : %s\n", tabMorse[index].lettre, tabMorse[index].morse);
    }

    return tabMorse;
}
```

But it doesn't as it would be : when executing the programm, the first printf (`printf("lettre : %c, morse : %s\n", tabMorse[index].lettre, tabMorse[index].morse);`) show me the thing that I want. However after this when I want to iterate through that array and display the structs, the letter field is the right but in the morse field I get a "" string, and I don't know why.

You can see below, a screen of the stdout when launching the program :

[image]
[image]

Do you know why it acts like that ?

Comment: `tabMorse[index].morse = morse;` then `free(morse);` then `printf("toto %c : %s\n", tabMorse[index].lettre, tabMorse[index].morse);` .. whoops, `tabMorse[index].morse` no longer points to valid memory, accessing it is UB.

Comment: There's no need to use `malloc()` for `stringFinal`. You only use it inside the loop and it has a fixed size, so just declare `char stringFinal[50];`

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII codes like `48`. Use `index + '0'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you call free(morse); around every iteration of the loop. So when you print it from the second loop the contents are undefined.

You also do not null terminate the morse[] string.

Answer (score 1):

```
    tabMorse[index].morse = morse;
    ...
    free(morse);
```

Since `tabMorse[index].morse` is equal to `morse`, `free(morse)` is the same as `free(tabMorse[index].morse)`, which is obviously not right.

You do not want to `free` the chunk of memory that you just stashed a pointer to. You need to keep it allocated so you can safely dereference the pointer later.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted (no use repeating), you cannot use pointers to heap memory that has been `free()`'d. (It's best to not duplicate pointers unless you really keep track of them.)

```
tabMorse[index].morse = morse;
/* 3 lines omitted */
free(morse);
```

Too much code *hides* problems such as this.

Take a step back and think about Morse Code. There are only two symbols, and no character is longer than 5 symbols (or is it 6 maximum?).

A byte (unsigned) has 8 bits that can be in one of two states.

Imagine "encoding" the Morse alphabet in the lowest bits of a byte, one byte per character. Because Morse code uses 1 to 5 symbols per character, another bit (on the left of the low bits) can be used as a flag meaning "the remaining bits on my right are to be used as 0=dot and 1=dash"... The Morse letter 'E' (one dot only) would be represented by 0b000000t0, where 't' would be the 'trigger' (always 1), and the lowest bit 0 would signify a single 'dot'.

The familiar "SOS" would be 0b00001000, 0b00001111, 0b00001000 ("... --- ...").

The code below has been adapted from something I wrote for Brail translation. The (incomplete) octal values in the table have NOT been checked as valid Brail but give you a start as to how you might, with the description above, encode 128 characters (7-bit ASCII) in Morse (replacing the Brail encoding). (The tables entries for 'S/s', 'O/o' and 'SP' have been adapted to be correct Morse characters.)

It seems this is a lot less code, and doesn't provide many corners for bugs to lurk.

```
void morsify( char c ) {
    unsigned char oct[] = { // TODO: adapt these values from Brail to Morse
    // CTRL codes
           0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    // CTRL codes
           0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    // punctuation
         000,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 002,   0,   0,   0,
    // punctuation & digits
           0, 001, 003, 011, 031, 021, 013, 033, 023, 012, 032,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    // @ + A-O
           0, 001, 003, 011, 031, 021, 013, 033, 023, 012, 032, 005, 007, 015, 035, 017,
    // P-Z + braces
         017, 037, 027, 010, 036, 045, 047, 072, 055, 075, 065,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    // ` + a-o
           0, 001, 003, 011, 031, 021, 013, 033, 023, 012, 032, 005, 007, 015, 035, 017,
    // p-z + braces
         017, 037, 027, 010, 036, 045, 047, 072, 055, 075, 065,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    };

    bool trig = false;
    uint8_t morse = oct[ c ]; // fetch copy of bit pattern from table
    for( uint8_t i = 0x80; i; i >>= 1 )
        if( !trig && (i & morse) ) // keep scanning right until trigger bit encountered
            trig = true;
        else if( trig ) // output has been triggered
            putchar( i & morse ? '-' : '.' ); // 1's = '-', 0's = '.'
    putchar( ' ' ); // space between characters
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "Stuff happens";

    puts( str );
    for( int i = 0; str[ i ]; i++ )
        morsify( str[ i ] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    char str1[] = "SOS sos SOS";

    puts( str1 );
    for( i = 0; str1[ i ]; i++ )
        morsify( str1[ i ] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return (0);
}
```

```
Stuff happens
... ---. ..-.- .-- .--  ..--  --- --- ...- --.- ...
SOS sos SOS
... --- ...  ... --- ...  ... --- ...
```

If you want to "buffer-up" the characters, simply replace the `putchar()` with your buffering scheme. Then you could output one long string instead of each individual dot/dash & SP.